# How to find the correct picture for this SVM classifier?

Tags: svm

There are different SVMs with different shapes/patterns of decision boundaries. The training data is labeled as yi ∈ {−1, 1}, represented as the shape of circles and squares respectively. Support vectors are drawn in solid circles.

Here is my question, how to find a hard-margin kernel SVM with $$k(u, v) = u · v + (u · v)^2 $$

I am thinking of 1 and 6, but interestingly, I can't see their difference except for the shape of the edge. They do have different support vector distributions, but does it really matter?

Does any one have any idea on this?

[image: different SVM classifications]

Comment: A quadratic kernel will have a parabola as the decision boundary.

Comment: So you think that is fig 5?